# clangd heats up the processor too much

Tags: language-server-protocol, clangd

I use lsp in emacs, which runs clangd. For large projects such as Unreal Engine where 1gb compile_commands are generated clangd consumes a lot of resources and heats up the processor, up to +90C. Are there any other flags, besides the ones already used, that can help to reduce its power?

```
"--pch-storage=disk" "--background-index=0" "-sync" "-enable-config=0" "-j=8"
```

Or perhaps there are some other ways to limit that kind of heating on his part?

Comment: You could reduce the value of the `-j` flag (number of parallel threads which clangd runs) to a lower value, e.g. `-j=4` or `-j=2`.